# Best practice: how do I tell if a collection/set/let is a Guava ImmutableSet/Immutable map?

Tags: java, guava

I've got a bug in my code, I'm trying to modify a List that is really a Guava ImmutableList passed in from a client program/programmer.

What is the best way to test for this, rather than waiting for the exception when the .add() fails?

Comment: For that matter, it would also be good to know if the list is one of the immutable collections returned from the JDK - `Collections.singletonList()` , `.emptyList()`, .. besides waiting for `.add()` to fail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What is the best way to test for this, rather than waiting for the exception when the .add() fails?

If you don't *know* if the returned list is mutable, you should copy it to a mutable collection anyway.  If the returned list is another `ArrayList`, the cost of the copy is minimal -- it reduces to a blazing fast `System.arraycopy`.

(That said, for the client library to sometimes return modifiable lists and sometimes unmodifiable lists is itself an act of evil.)

If you must check at runtime, use `instanceof ImmutableMap` or `ImmutableCollection` or whatever's appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

For specific Guava, you could check if the instance is a com.google.common.collect.ImmutableCollection.

```
if (list instanceof com.google.common.collect.ImmutableCollection) {
   // is immutable
}
```

For immutable map you need to check if instance is a `com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap`

Answer (score 2):

Checking if the list is one of the ImmutableCollection subtypes is easy:

```
if (list instanceof ImmutableCollection) {
    // do whatever you want to do if the list is a Guava immutable collection/set/list/multiset
}
```

However that does not give you a generic solution of figuring out if the list is immutable or not (there may be user-implemented lists that are immutable or the unmodifiable list obtained from Collections.unmodifiableList()).

So if you want a generic solution, you still have to catch exceptions list.add() method may throw.

Comment: maybe checking if it is ImmutableCollection would be better... as the check should be done for a list

Answer (score 0):

'`instanceof`' is definitely okay.

But if possible I would recommend use `ImmutableList` in method signature instead of `List`. Because `ImmutableList` is-a `List` in syntax, but actually `ImmutableList` throws `UnsupportedOperationException` when `addXXX()`, `removeXXX()`, `clear()` is called.